# CMake export an imported library retrieved with find package

Tags: cmake

I'd like to import a library retrieved with find_package, and then export an alias. Anyway this code

```
  set(mylib_DIR ${lib_install_dir})
  
  find_package(my_lib 3.5.2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
   
  # find package returns library_dir and include_dir, no target

  set(my_lib mylibname)

  add_library(${my_lib}_imp SHARED IMPORTED)

  set_property(TARGET ${my_lib}_imp PROPERTY
      IMPORTED_LOCATION ${library_dir})

  target_include_directories(${my_lib}_imp INTERFACE ${include_dir})

  add_library(myns::${my_lib} ALIAS ${my_lib}_imp)

  set_property(TARGET ${my_lib}_imp PROPERTY EXPORT_NAME myns::${my_lib}) -> error
```

gives an error

```
CMake Error at cmake/libigl.cmake:446 (set_property):
  EXPORT_NAME property can't be set on imported targets ("mylib_imp")
```

Is there a way to export an imported library this manner? Is there a workaround, maybe creating a dummy target, I don't know...
Note tha find_package in my case retrieves only the shared lib and the includes, as from an installed library, and declares no target. For CMake there are no sources here, just a bunch of files.
Thanks in advance

Comment: CMake doesn't provide a mechanism for export imported target. Instead, you could add the code which creates that imported target into the config script of your project.

Comment: Ok, fine, thank you